# Template class with get function ALWAYS returning reference,

Tags: c++, templates, reference

How is it possible to have a templated class here called

**FrontBackBuffer** with template parameter **TBackBufferType, TFrontBufferType**

```cpp
template< typename TBufferTypeFront, typename TBufferTypeBack = TBufferTypeFront>
class FrontBackBuffer{
  public:
  explicit FrontBackBuffer(
     TBufferTypeFront const & m_front,
     TBufferTypeBack  const & m_back):
     m_Front(m_front),
     m_Back(m_back)
  {
  };

  ~FrontBackBuffer()
  {};

  typename std::remove_reference<
    typename std::remove_pointer<TBufferTypeFront>::type
  >::type  & getFront(){return m_Front;}    // error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'A&' from expression of type 'A*'| (here T is A)


  typename std::remove_reference<
    typename std::remove_pointer<TBufferTypeBack>::type 
  >::type  & getBack(){return m_Back;}

  TBufferTypeFront m_Front;       ///< The front buffer
  TBufferTypeBack m_Back;         ///< The back buffer

};
```

I would like to achieve the following:

- to be consistent in the code, I would prefere, to no matter what the Type inside the buffer is,  to have a function **getFront/Back** which should always return a Reference to the buffer (either a const or a non-const depending on the type: e.g const int = T should return a const int & reference! I would like to write code like this

  ```
  FrontBuffer<const int&, std::vector<int> > a;
  a.getFront() = 4 //COmpile error! OK!;
  a.getBack()[0] = 4;
  FrontBuffer< int*, GAGAType * > b;
  b.getBack() = GAGAType();
  b.getFront() = int(4);  // this is no ERROR, i would like to get the reference of the memory location pointet by int* ....
  ```

I would like this because I want to avoid changing the syntax if I change the buffer type from reference to pointer (where I need to dereference)

- Is such a Buffer class possible to accept with all possible types (like shared_ptr)
  asd
- All I want is some access and it should be very performant, no copies and so on
- I dont know really how to write this generic buffer? Somebody has any clue?

Thanks!!!

**EDIT1** I want also to be able to assign to the dereferenced pointer:

```
b.getFront() = int(4);  // this is no ERROR, i would like to get the reference of the memory location pointet by int* ....
```

Thats where my problem with traits comes in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specialize ([traits technique](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#traits)) part of your template, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyRefTypes {
    typedef const T & Con;
    typedef T& Ref;
    typedef const T& CRef;
    static Ref getRef(T& v) {
        return v;
    }
};
```

**Update**
Note the special function for returning reference - it is needed if you want to behave differently for pointers - returns references for it.
**End Update**

And make specialization for references and const references:

```
template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T&> {
        typedef T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T&> {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T> {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };
```

**Update**
And this "special" specialization for pointers - so they will work as references:

```
//Specialization for pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T*> {
        typedef T* Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef T* const CRef;  //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ref getRef(T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T*> {
        typedef const T* Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T* const CRef; //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ref getRef(const T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };
```

((However I am not sure this specialization for pointers is a good design... ))

**End Update**

And usage inside your class template:

```
template< typename TBufferTypeFront, typename TBufferTypeBack = TBufferTypeFront>
class FrontBackBuffer{
  public:


   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Ref TBufferTypeFrontRef;
   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::CRef TBufferTypeFrontCRef;
   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Con TBufferTypeFrontCon;

   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Ref TBufferTypeBackRef;
   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::CRef TBufferTypeBackCRef;
   typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Con TBufferTypeBackCon;

  explicit FrontBackBuffer(
     TBufferTypeFrontCon m_front,
     TBufferTypeBackCon m_back):
     m_Front(m_front),
     m_Back(m_back)
  {
  };

  ~FrontBackBuffer()
  {};
  // See here special functions from traits are used:
  TBufferTypeFrontRef getFront(){return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::getRef(m_Front); }    
  TBufferTypeBackRef getBack(){return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack>::getRef(m_Back); }

  TBufferTypeFront m_Front;       ///< The front buffer
  TBufferTypeBack m_Back;         ///< The back buffer

};
```

It works as expected:
http://ideone.com/e7xfoN

Comment: @Gabriel: don't forget to accept Piotr's answer if it does what you need (+1 from myself, btw).

Comment: Ehm, not quite, I have just checked!
I maybee did not make it clear is see edit above!

Comment: @Gabriel - use `b.getFront() = new int(4);`... this `new` makes a difference

Comment: Hehe, one moment:
I would like that when I have a pointer as the underlying type that even when I call getBack() that it returns a reference to the memory location pointet by the pointer inside!  I dont want to set the pointer new or change it :-) I want the value :-)

Comment: @Gabriel - no problem - add this note to your question - I will change  my answer so it will work for pointers too, just as you wish ;)

Comment: @Gabriel - I did the changes for pointers - however I am not sure this is a good idea - consider pointer to pointers `T**`, references to pointers `T*&` - I have no idea how it should work - hope you are not going to use such strange constructions...  But the lesson learned is that you can do almost whatever you want with using of traits... BTW I added link to nice boost page about this

Comment: @ PiotrNycz When I run it, it does not work, Changed Constructor to Ref  -> http://ideone.com/P7Ow25
Why does it not work?? I dont get this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19305/discussion-between-gabriel-and-piotrnycz)

Comment: EDITED! SO THAT IT WORKS! ADDED type for Constructor =)

Comment: @Gabriel yes you are right I made mistake in T& case. Your version with Con is better and correct.